# Repeated background image in Chrome v47

Tags: google-chrome, background-image, background-repeat

Since the upgrade to Chrome 47 printing web pages gives a problem. We have a background image that is repeated on each printed page. Since Chrome 47 this image is in low resolution/bad quality. If the image is not repeated the quality is fine.

```css
#bodyContent {
    background-image:url('/images/Letter.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

gives good result: sharp image on printed page.

```css
#bodyContent {
    background-image:url('/images/Letter.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

gives bad result: blurred, low-res, bad quality image.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?